# How do I configure axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin to use multiple classes to generate one wsdl?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsdl, apache-axis

In my project POM I have configured in build | plugins | plugin | configuration, the `className` tag that specifies one of the many classes for the services I want to offer. There are more though.

How do I configure the axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin to read multiple classes for all the services I wrote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a good approach. There should be a separate WSDL for each service, otherwise it violates the concept of modularization. There are few suggestions for a workaround in this question.
[Generating Single WSDL file for Multiple  classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459301/generating-single-wsdl-file-for-multiple-classes)

Comment: Understood. Thanks. But then how do I configure this maven plugin in the pom.xml to generate multiple wsdl files for  the different service classes in my project? If I specify multiple <className> tags, one for each class, in the <configuration> section for the plugin, I get only one wsdl file, the one from the last className listed. How can I get them all? Thanks.

Comment: It is better to ask that as a separate question. Search for the similar questions before posting. And accept this, if you believe this is the answer for this question.